# Fastest way to slice multiple Dask dataframe based on the date ranges from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

What would be the fastest approach to select only the dates in df1 date ranges from a ddf2 Dask dataframe? All dates out of ranges should be dropped.

**df1 - Pandas dataframe with start end date ranges**

```
        start       end
01 2018-06-25 2018-06-29
02 2019-05-06 2019-05-13
...
```

**dd2 - Dask dataframe (30M rows)**

(*) marked rows has to be selected

```
    date        value1
    2018-01-01  23
    2018-01-01  24
    2018-01-02  545
    2018-01-03  433
    2018-01-04  23
    *2018-06-25 234
    *2018-06-25 50
    *2018-06-25 120
    *2018-06-26 22
    *2018-06-27 32       
    *2018-06-27 123
    *2018-06-28 603
    *2018-06-29 625
    2019-01-01  734
    2019-01-01  241
    2019-01-01  231
    2019-01-02  211
    2019-01-02  214
    2019-05-05  234
    2019-05-05  111
    *2019-05-06 846
    *2019-05-06 231
    *2019-05-07 654
    *2019-05-07 119
    *2019-05-08 212
    *2019-05-08 122
    *2019-05-06 765
    *2019-05-13 231
    *2019-05-13 213
    *2019-05-13 443
    2019-05-14  321
    2019-05-14  231
    2019-05-15  123
...
```

**Output: Dask dataframe need it with appended slices**

```
date        value1   
2018-06-25  234
2018-06-25  50
2018-06-25  120
2018-06-26  22
2018-06-27  32
2018-06-27  123
2018-06-28  603
2018-06-29  625
2019-05-06  846
2019-05-06  231
2019-05-07  654
2019-05-07  119
2019-05-08  212
2019-05-08  122
2019-05-06  765
2019-05-13  231
2019-05-13  213
2019-05-13  443
```

This code is working but I need to pass start & end date ranges in df1 to filter dd2 without hardcoding dates manually.

```
dd2 = dd2[
    (dd2['date'] >= '2018-06-25') & (dd2['date'] <= '2018-06-29') |
    (dd2['date'] >= '2019-05-06') & (dd2['date'] <= '2019-05-13')
]
```

Comment: Do any of your date ranges in `df1` overlap?

Comment: @Vince please add output for `cumsum` so I can add into my answer.

Comment: Hello @PhilipKendall. No, ranges do not overlap

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might work:

```py
from itertools import starmap

date_ddf = ddf.set_index("date")
slices = starmap(slice, df.values)

# There might be a more "Pandas-esque" way to do this, but I 
# don't know it yet.
sliced = map(date_ddf.__getitem__, slices)

# We have to reify the `map` object into a `list` for Dask.
concat_ddf = dd.concat(list(sliced))

concat_ddf.compute()
```

Each pass through the `map` on `date_ddf.__getitem__` returns you a cut of the original frame hence the need for the `dd.concat` to bring it back together.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, but using list comprehension to slice by the index, and with verification (at the end) that the slicing is done correctly.

Imports

```
from datetime import datetime

import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dask import compute
```

Specify adjustable inputs

```
# Start date from which to create dummy data to use
data_start_date = "1700-01-01"
# Frequency of dummy data created (hourly)
data_freq = "H"
# number of rows of data to generate
nrows = 3_000_000
# Dask DataFrame chunk size; will be used later to determine how many files
# (of the dummy data generated here) will be exported to disk
chunksize = 75_000
```

Generate `df1` with slicing boundary dates

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [
        {"start": datetime(1850, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0), "end": datetime(1870, 9, 4, 23, 0, 0)},
        {"start": datetime(1880, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0), "end": datetime(1895, 4, 9, 23, 0, 0)},
        {"start": datetime(1910, 11, 25, 0, 0, 0), "end": datetime(1915, 5, 5, 23, 0, 0)},
        {"start": datetime(1930, 10, 8, 0, 0, 0), "end": datetime(1940, 2, 8, 23, 0, 0)},
        {"start": datetime(1945, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0), "end": datetime(1950, 1, 3, 23, 0, 0)},
    ]
)
print(df1)
       start                 end
0 1850-01-06 1870-09-04 23:00:00
1 1880-07-06 1895-04-09 23:00:00
2 1910-11-25 1915-05-05 23:00:00
3 1930-10-08 1940-02-08 23:00:00
4 1945-09-09 1950-01-03 23:00:00
```

Create dummy data

- we'll assign a column here named `wanted` with all rows being `False`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(nrows),
    index=pd.date_range(data_start_date, periods=nrows, freq="h"),
    columns=["value1"],
)
df.index.name = "date"
df["wanted"] = False
print(df.head())
                       value1  wanted
date                                 
1700-01-01 00:00:00  0.504119   False
1700-01-01 01:00:00  0.582796   False
1700-01-01 02:00:00  0.383905   False
1700-01-01 03:00:00  0.995389   False
1700-01-01 04:00:00  0.592130   False
```

Now, we'll change the wanted rows to `True` if the rows have the same dates as those in `df1`

- the reason for doing this is so that we can check later that our slicing is correct
- this step and the `wanted` column are not necessary in your real use-case, but are only required to check our work

```
for _, row in df1.iterrows():
    df.loc[row['start']: row['end'], "wanted"] = True
df = df.reset_index()
print(df.head())
print(df["wanted"].value_counts().to_frame())
                 date    value1  wanted
0 1700-01-01 00:00:00  0.504119   False
1 1700-01-01 01:00:00  0.582796   False
2 1700-01-01 02:00:00  0.383905   False
3 1700-01-01 03:00:00  0.995389   False
4 1700-01-01 04:00:00  0.592130   False
        wanted
False  2530800
True    469200
```

Note that calling `.value_counts()` on the `wanted` column shows the number of `True` values in this column that we should expect if we've correctly sliced our data. This was done using data in a `pandas.DataFrame`, but later we'll do this with this same data in a `dask.DataFrame`.

Now, we'll export the data to multiple `.parquet` files locally

- often, we'll want to start with the data loaded directly from disk into `dask`
- to export the data to multiple `.parquet` flies, we'll convert the `pandas.DataFrame` to a `dask.DataFrame` and then set the `chunksize` parameter which will determine how many files are created (`chunksize` rows will be placed in each exported file - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63780962/4057186))

```
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, chunksize=chunksize)
ddf.to_parquet("data", engine="auto")
```

Now load all the `.parquet` files directly into a single `dask.DataFrame` and set the `date` column as the index

- it is computationally expensive to set the index, but we're only specifying this when reading the file directly into a `dask.DataFrame` and not changing it after that

```
ddf = dd.read_parquet(
    "data/",
    dtype={"value1": "float64"},
    index="date",
    parse_dates=["date"],
)
print(ddf)
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                      value1 wanted
npartitions=40                     
1700-01-01 00:00:00  float64   bool
1708-07-23 00:00:00      ...    ...
...                      ...    ...
2033-09-07 00:00:00      ...    ...
2042-03-28 23:00:00      ...    ...
Dask Name: read-parquet, 40 tasks
```

Now, we're ready to slice using the dates in `df1`. We'll do this with list comprehension to iterate over each row in `df1`, use the row to slice the data (in the `dask.DataFrame`) and then call `dd.concat` (as @joebeeson did)

```
slices = dd.concat([ddf.loc[row['start']: row['end']] for _, row in df1.iterrows()])
```

Finally, compute on this list of delayed `dask` objects to get a single `pandas.DataFrame` sliced to give the required dates

```
ddf_sliced_computed = compute(slices)[0].reset_index()
print(ddf_sliced_computed.head())
print(ddf_sliced_computed["wanted"].value_counts().to_frame())
                 date    value1  wanted
0 1850-01-06 00:00:00  0.671781    True
1 1850-01-06 01:00:00  0.455022    True
2 1850-01-06 02:00:00  0.490212    True
3 1850-01-06 03:00:00  0.240171    True
4 1850-01-06 04:00:00  0.162088    True
      wanted
True  469200
```

As you can see, we've sliced out rows with the correct number of `True` values in the `wanted` column. We can explicitly verify this using the `pandas.DataFrame` that we used earlier to generate the dummy data that was later written to disk

```
assert all(ddf_sliced_computed["wanted"] == True)
assert (
    df[df["wanted"] == True]
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .equals(ddf_sliced_computed[ddf_sliced_computed["wanted"] == True])
)
```

**Notes**

1. This uses 3M rows. You are working with 30M rows, so you'll have to modify the dummy data generated at the start if you want to check timings, etc.